# My .db file is coming up empty when I try to view it on DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: android, database, android-studio

I have a database file in my `/Assets` folder of my Android application.

My app runs fine. I can save data to the .db file and I can also retrieve the data in my listview, however when I try to pull it from the `/data/data/com.example.package/databases` in the device file explorer and open it in DB browser for SQLite, there are no entries. 
File size is 16 kb.

I'm using Android Studio v 3.4.2 and running API 23 for my app.

Why can't I see the data in the .db file?

Comment: Do you also copy the ```.db-shm``` and ```.db-wal``` files? Also, when your Device File Explorer is open, do you select the files and right click + synchronize?

Comment: @axierjhtjz No I don't. I only have 3 files in the databases folder. The .db file, the MyDB file, and the MyDB-journal file. MyDB is the name of my database.

How do i copy the -shm and wal files?

Comment: How are you extracting the files from the Emulator? With the Android Studio Device File Explorer?

Comment: @axierjhtjz yep. I saw a tutorial where you can browse through the device file explorer and just copy the .db file in /data/data/com.example.package/databases

Comment: Are you sure you are exporting dB from same device on which you are running your app ?

Comment: @mightyWOZ I mean yeah, I'm saving the .db file which is the database file